# Stable homotopy groups as a generalized (reduced) homology theory

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, limits-colimits, stable-homotopy-theory

It is known that $\pi_*^{st}$ defines a generalized homology theory, where $\pi_n^{st}(X) = \text{colim}_{k \geq 0} \pi_{n+k}(\Sigma^k X)$ is the $n$th stable homotopy group of the based space $X$. That is, the functors $\pi_n^{st}$ satisfy the Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms for generalized homology theories. As such, among other properties, the following two conditions hold :

- $\pi_n^{st}(X)$ is an abelian group.
- The homotopy axiom is satisfied. That is, continuous, homotopic maps $f,g : X \rightarrow Y$ induce the same maps $\pi_n^{st}(f), \pi_n^{st}(g) : \pi_n^{st}(X) \rightarrow \pi_n^{st}(Y)$ for all $n$.

I'd like a better understanding for why each of these conditions holds for stable homotopy groups. In the colimit that defines $\pi_n^{st}(X)$, each homotopy group that appears isn't necessarily abelian, since the fundamental group of a space may certainly be non-abelian. Thus, why does it follow that $\pi_n^{st}(X)$ is abelian ? Further, how can we rigorously show the homotopy axiom holds ?

Thanks !

Comment: The colimit (or direct limit) of a direct sequence of groups will be abelian whenever it happens that all but finitely many groups in the sequence are abelian.

Comment: @LeeMosher That's an excellent result. Do you have a reference for it ?

Comment: It follows immediately from the fact that the direct limit is a homomorphic image of each term in the direct sequence.

Comment: @LeeMosher Aah, I see ! So we may view the direct limit as the homomorphic image of one of the abelian homotopy groups that appears in the sequence. Hence, this direct limit is abelian. Thank you!

Comment: It is good to remember that in a direct limit you can chop off the first n groups for any n and not affect the limit.

Comment: @ConnorMalin Indeed. One can show that the stable homotopy groups satisfy the suspension axiom for generalized homology theories using exactly what you've stated. I believe it follows from the universal property of the colimit.

Comment: Yes, I think the proper way to think of stable homotopy groups (and why it might form a homology theory) is that you are forcing the suspension axiom to hold just by definitions. What remains to check is that for a CW pair $(X,A)$ the sequence $A \rightarrow X \rightarrow X/A$ is exact after applying stable homotopy groups.

Comment: @ConnorMalin This would be worth an official answer.